# C++ Threading with multidimensional vectors - access violation

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, multidimensional-array

I'm currently trying to get work done in a threaded member function of my class. Therefore it gets a 2d array as parameter and fills it in the member function. This gets repeated multiple times. Right after spawning the first thread I get an error with either read or write access violation. I tried different approaches to solve it, but can't get it to work. While I found nearly any problem already solved here, in this case I was unsuccessful finding something for quite a while now.

```
void myClass::process(Vector3D& out_stack, long filterFaktor){
    long rowSize = this->input2D.size();
    long colSize = this->input2D.at(0).size();
    int filterPerRowCount = ceil((double)rowSize / filterFaktor);
    int filterPerColCount = ceil((double)colSize / filterFaktor);   

    std::vector<std::thread> threadPool;
    //create new filter
    long currentrow = 0;    
    while (currentrow < rowSize) {
        long currentcol = 0;
        while (currentcol < colSize) {          
            Filter* nextFilter = &this->createNextFilter(currentrow, currentcol, filterPerRowCount, filterPerColCount);                             
            out_stack.push_back(Vector2D());
            Vector2D* nptr = &out_stack[out_stack.size()-1];

            //Here we are calling the thread which leads to the access violation
            threadPool.push_back(std::thread(&myClass::nextProcess, this, nextFilter, nptr, rowSize, colSize));

            currentcol += filterPerColCount;            
        }
        currentrow += filterPerRowCount;
    }   
    //wait until threads have finished
    for (int iThread = 0; iThread < threadPool.size(); iThread++) {
        threadPool[iThread].join();
    }
}

void myClass::nextProcess(Filter* nextfilter, Vector2D* out_Map, long rowCount, long colCount){
    //Loops this part -> creates the rows and pushes them in the out_Map
        std::vector<double> nextRowInMap;
        //... Calculates sum
        nextRowInMap.push_back(sum);        

    //Push row in vector -> This is where the error occurs
    out_Map->push_back(nextRowInMap);       
}       


typedef std::vector<double> Vector1D;
typedef std::vector<Vector1D> Vector2D;
typedef std::vector<Vector2D> Vector3D;
```

I think I'm just missing knowledge in using Pointers in C++, cause I'm new to it.

Thanks in advance & best regards

**EDIT**

Tried it now this way, still doesn't work:

```
out_stack.push_back(Vector2D());
long index = out_stack.size() - 1;                  
threadPool.push_back(std::thread(&myClass::nextProcess, this, nextFilter, &out_stack, index, rowSize, colSize));
```

And in nextProcess:

```
out_stack->at(index).push_back(nextRowInMap);
```

**EDIT**

Solved with `mutex`. Additionally I needed to pass the filter not on reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error is here:

```
out_stack.push_back(Vector2D());
Vector2D* nptr = &out_stack[out_stack.size()-1];
```

There is no guarantee that the object stays at the same address when you modify the vector.
When the vector has to grow it can allocate the internal memory on another address and move the objects in the vector to a new address. So the pointer can get invalid on the next `push_back`

You should pass the vector and index to the thread and access it each time you need it

```
out_stack[index].push_back(...)
```

It may be that after `out_stack[index]` and before `push_back` the vector gets modified and you are also operating on invalid memory. So you should protect accessing/modifying the vector with a `std::mutex`. I am not sure on that last part though if there is some thread safety guarantee there I don't know of.

Comment: I tried with passing the whole 3D vector and the new created index, but still got the error. Maybe i need to try mutex.